# How to serialize array in JavaScript calling Web.api

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-web-api

Posting an array to web.api (api controller) does not work in it's most simple form I guess.

I have this JavaScript

```
var ann = { Age: 11, Name: 'Ann' };
var bob = { Age: 22, Name: 'Bob' };
var list = [ann, bob];

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/myapi/',
    data:list,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
});
```

And then I have a web.api with a simple post handler

```
public void Post(JObject pList)
{
    //Whatever
}
```

If I change "data:list" with "data:ann" then everything works as expected (except bob doesn't come over of course). But the minute I put a list then it doesn't work.

I have tried to look up solutions, and some seem to serialize manually in JavaScript, is that the correct "solution"/"best practice" to this issue, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may work for you

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/myapi/',
    data: JSON.stringify(list),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: "POST",
});
```

And your controller

```
public void Post(List<yourobject> list)
{
    //Whatever
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess that answers the question that serializing in JavaScript is the best solution. The fact that Web.api then gets a list is a clear reading improvement to what I else was trying to do

Answer (score 1):

just change your ajax request to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/myapi/',
    data:list,
    traditional: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
});
```

read this if you want some more informations: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: Even with trational then my JObject looks like: base {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer} = {
  "undefined": [
    "",
    ""
  ]
}